# How to write a SQL query for user selected date range?

Tags: sql, coldfusion-6

I am trying to write a query that will capture calls completed within 24 hours and calls completed > 24 hours, by call rep, based off of user selected from date and to date range in a web form. I have a column for `completion_date` in the "yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00" format, reps, type of call, call requested, and call assigned.

I really need some help!

Comment: What SQL server are you using Oracle, MS SQL, MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to figure out the query, something like this should work:

```
SELECT reps, completion_date
FROM dbo
WHERE completion_date < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @DateSelectedByUser), -1)
```

This should get you the results within 24 hours, now for the results over 24 hours, you just use `>` rather than `<`

Comment: @Nacole - if it works for you, would you mind marking me as the answer?

Comment: Wow, nice usage of "the defaults", +1 from me!